# MySQL Big FK identifier

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, restriction

I'm trying to create a fk but MySQL doesn't allow it ...

```
Identifier name 'foobarbaz_FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_WEEE_DISCOUNT_PRODUCT_ENTITY' is too long [ CREATE TABLE `foobarbaz_weee_discount` (   `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `customer_group_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,   `value` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',   KEY `foobarbaz_FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_WEEE_DISCOUNT_WEBSITE` (`website_id`),   KEY `foobarbaz_FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_WEEE_DISCOUNT_PRODUCT_ENTITY` (`entity_id`),   KEY `foobarbaz_FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_WEEE_DISCOUNT_GROUP` (`customer_group_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; ]
```

Is there a way to add big fks?
Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

No, it's hard coded into MySQL, see [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) (towards the bottom of the page).  But it has nothing to do with the name of the FK.  It's the name of the index that's too long (64 characters max):

```
`Identifier`                  `Maximum Length (characters)`
Database                      64
Table                         64
Column                        64
Index                         64
Constraint                    64
Stored Procedure or Function  64
Trigger                       64
View                          64
Alias                         256 (see exception following table)
Compound Statement Label      16
```

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key is not the problem. It's the **name** of the key. I agree with MySQL, `'foobarbaz_FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_WEEE_DISCOUNT_PRODUCT_ENTITY'` is a bit silly :)

You have "PRODUCT_ENTITY" twice in the name. Start by dropping that :)

Comment: You better delete your comment, as it doesn't matter how many times `PRODUCT_ENTITY` is written as long it has a maximum of 64 characters (the limit set by mysql).

Comment: LOL, no no no... I'm very seriously holding on to the belief that MySQL inspects the actual name and at its own mystical whims and fancies decides that some names are apparently "bad". In addition (but obviously not as important and factually true), my answer serves as a reminder that some problems are best solved by not causing them in the first place.

Comment: Mysql is checking for the name, but for other reasons. Not to check if a key contains a substring twice.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this may be a bug. Here is the report that I found. I didn't see that it was patched yet but you can just rename your keys so that then length is shorter.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13942